# Bugzilla 4.2.2: Adding attachment parameter to enter_bug.cgi call

Tags: perl, cgi, bugzilla, mod-perl

On Bugzilla 4.2.2, I can set up default text for a bug with a call like:

http://bugzilla.foo.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=foobar&short_desc=foobaz%20is%20broken

But I am not sure what to modify, or what parameter to pass, to get a default attachment filled in. The API documentation has information about attachments that already exist, or how to create an attachment once a bug has been filed, but not to (say) fill in the text block with the contents of a file. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The `enter_bug.cgi` form on bugzilla.mozilla.org, includes a textarea called `attach_text` that would seem to do what you want. Maybe something like this would work for you:

> http://bugzilla.foo.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=foobar&short_desc=foobaz%20is%20broken&attach_text=this%20is%20the%20text%20of%20the%20attachment

YMMV, depending on the version of Bugzilla you're using and whether this parameter is supported in stock Bugzilla or just the Mozilla installation. You will also be subject to whatever limits your user-agent and HTTP server put on query string length.